# How to fix syntax error in OCaml - could be to do with 'in' keyword?

Tags: ocaml

I am relatively new to ocaml and was trying to figure out where the syntax error is in my code but cannot find it, could it be that I am using the 'in' keyword incorrectly?

```
let dayFromDate year month day = 
        if ( (month = 1) || (month = 2) )
        then let m = month + 12 in
        else let m = month
        
        let k = year mod 100 in
        let j = year / 100 in 
        let q = day in
        
        let h = ( q + ( ( 13 * (m + 1) ) / 5) + k + (k / 4) + 5 - j ) 
        
        h;;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely have some issues around `let ... in ...`

I think what you meant was:

```
let dayFromDate year month day = 
  let m = if month = 1 || month = 2 then month + 12 else month in
  let k = year mod 100 in
  let j = year / 100 in 
  let q = day in
  let h = q + ((13 * (m + 1)) / 5) + k + (k / 4) + 5 - j in
  h;;
```

Remember also that `if/else` is an expression that returns a value.